# Bash/How to "cut" the current day with cal?

Tags: bash

I have the following script to highlight the current date in a calendar:

```
$ cal | grep --color -E6 "\b$(date +%e | sed 's/ //g')\b"
```

The result:

[image: 1]

How can I cut a value with current date (output should be just the number of the current day: 2 or 02 in the example)? I need to use the "cal" function.
Out:

```
2
```

This construction:

```
$ date +%d
```

does not satisfy the task condition, unfortunately.

Comment: What do you mean by "cut a value"? Could you show expected output? Also, using `sed` to trim whitespace seems like using a hammer, you could use `tr -d ' ' ` instead

Comment: @suvayu added output to question. On the output - just the number of the day of the current date (2 or 02 for today, for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want today's date, why do you need `cal`?  Just use `date +%e`.

But for what ever reason, if you want to only print the matched date with `grep`, use `-o`.

```
$ cal | grep --color=never -o "\b$(date +%e | tr -d ' ' )\b"
2
```

Or maybe you just want to trim the leading whitespace, in that case just use the `date` & `tr` command:

```
$ date +%e | tr -d ' '
2
```